# Upload an image using photoshop api

Tags: c#, photoshop-script

I want to save the image opened in photoshop and upload it on the database. Is there a way to do this using PS APIs?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know PS is not able to do this. PS is able to save the image to a specific place.
(Which could be a mounted network drive).

I would tell PS to save it to a specific local folder. This folder is constantly checked by a script / progam which does the upload / database work.